# Updating to the database in php

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to get the code to update some data that has been selected by the user.

What is happening is that its updating everything in that column to the value the user has edited it to.

**For example** i have bob, bob1, bob2 and i want to select bob1 to edit. I then edit it so bob1 is now fred1, when it updates it updates every value to fred1. So there is 3 fred1's.

Could someone help? please.

**update.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once 'connection.php';

if (isset($_POST['update'])) {
    $success = updateValue($_POST['name']);


    if (!$success) 
        echo 'Sorry, the update failed';
    session_destroy();
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Main Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method='post'>   
        View a Member's Details:
        <select name='members' value='members'id="Mmembers">       
            <?php
            $results = getResults('members');
            if ($results) {
                foreach ($results as $row) {
                    echo '<option value="' . $row['member_id'] . '">' . $row['name'] . '</option>';
                }
            }
            else
                echo '<option value="0"0"> No Data</option>';
            ?>

        </select>

        <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit"/>
        <br/> 
        <br/>
    </form>

    <?php
    if (isset($_POST['members'])) {


        $ResultSet = getMemberResults(($_POST['members']));
        echo "<h1> Member Details. </h1>";
        echo "<table border='1' cellpadding='6'>";
        echo "<tr> <th>Id</th> <th>Name</th>";

        foreach ($ResultSet as $row) {
            echo "<form action=update.php method=POST>";
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>" . "<input type=text name=member_id value=" . $row ['member_id'] . " </td>";
            echo "<td>" . "<input type=text name=name value=" . $row ['name'] . "     </td>";
            echo "<td>" . "<input type=submit name=update value=update" . " </td>";
            echo "</tr>";
            echo "</form>";
        }
        echo "</table>";
    }
    ?>

</body>
</html>
```

**connection.php**

```
<?php

//Connect to the database
function getSQLConnection() {
    $mysqlConnection = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=', "root", "");

    return $mysqlConnection;
}

//Get all results from members table
function getResults($tablename) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM " . $tablename;

    $mysqlConnection = getSQLConnection();

    $ResultSet = $mysqlConnection->query($sql);
    return $ResultSet;
}


function getMemberResults($id) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM members WHERE members.member_id = '$id'";

    $mysqlConnection = getSQLConnection();

    $ResultSet = $mysqlConnection->query($sql);
    return $ResultSet;
}

function updateValue($id) {
    $sql = "UPDATE members SET name='$id' WHERE members.member_id = members.member_id";

    $mysqlConnection = getSQLConnection();

    $ResultSetting = $mysqlConnection->query($sql);
    return $ResultSetting;
}

?>
```

Comment: I took out my db name, for safe.

Comment: @WayneC Oh okay haha, can you help me get it to edit that one single value instead of editing all of it to the same thing at once

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your SQL UPDATE statement is incorrect.

```
WHERE members.member_id = members.member_id
```

The above where is always going to resolve true for all rows, making your call

```
UPDATE members SET name='$id'
```

You should set the name and also add the members id (a unique identity) in the `WHERE` cause.

```
/** give functions descriptive names **/
function updateMemberName($id, $name) {
  $sql = "UPDATE members SET name='$name' WHERE id = '$id'";
  //...
```

**update.php**

You would then just need to modify the function call

```
if (isset($_POST['update'])) {
    $success = updateMemberName($_POST['member_id'], $_POST['name']);
```

Comment: How will this work with the isset bit on the update.php? @AlexP

Answer (score 0):

```
function updateValue($id) {
$sql = "UPDATE members SET name='$id' WHERE members.member_id = members.member_id";
```

This is equivalent to

```
UPDATE members SET name='$id'
```

as the where clause evaluates to TRUE for all rows

Answer (score 0):

Answering only to make it work like you expect it to, This function:

```
function updateValue($id) {
$sql = "UPDATE members SET name='$id' WHERE members.member_id = members.member_id";
...
}
```

Needs to be

```
function updateValue($id, $value) {
$sql = "UPDATE members SET name='$value' WHERE members.member_id=$id";
...
}
```